# Websockets won't start on live server - ssl error 303

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, ssl

Hey there I have a huge issue. I created a web socket system using the Ratchet framework for pho. It works perfectly fine on my local server but for some reason it won't work on my live server. My server is on digital ocean so I'm pretty familiar with the server. I use Apache also. But this is how my we sockets JavaScript code look right now for connecting:

```
if(typeof(WebSocket) == "function")
{
    var host = "wss://www.frindse.com:8181/?chathash=" + mainChatId;
    var conn = new WebSocket(host);

    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");

        // Send back the chat id
        conn.send(JSON.stringify({event: "supplyChatHash", data: mainChatId}));

        // Add this new user to the connection
        conn.send(JSON.stringify({event: "connectNewUserToChat", data: {userId: logged, connectedTo: mainChatId}}));
    };

    conn.onclose = function(e) {
        alert('Disconnected');
    };
}
```

And here is the code for starting the server:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new ChatServerBackend($_GET['chathash'])
        )
    ),
    8181
);
```

For some reason my we sockets server won't start on my live site. Does it have to do with a port? Or anything else?